# Tkinter entry output

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am creating a Data finder using a db file and i use tkinter entry. however in the console it returns the output `[]` and the code is this

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter

db = sqlite3.connect ('covidjakartadb.db')

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter a area")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%{0}%'".format(entry)

cursor = sqlite3.Cursor(db)

cursor.execute(select_all)

def Search_Completed():
    label = tkinter.Label(window,  text="aaaaa")

Button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Search data", command=Search_Completed)
Button.pack()



positive = cursor.fetchall()

print (positive)

window.mainloop()
```

This project is due today so a answer today would be greatful

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce as I don't have your database, but from the code I'd say that the database is returning "[]" from your query. Have you tried querying the database manually?

Comment: The WHERE clause in your SQL statement is invalid.  It should be something like `"SELECT * FROM locations WHERE field_name LIKE '%{0}%'".format(entry.get())`.  Replace `field_name` with the actual field you want to use.

Comment: @figbeam yes i have tried and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to select from the database needs to be in the `search_completed` function.  As written it runs before the GUI is even open.

The search should be using the contents of the Entry, `entry.get()` not `entry`.

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter

db = sqlite3.connect ('covidjakartadb.db')

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("500x300")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please enter a area")
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

def Search_Completed():
    # select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%{0}%'".format(entry)
    # select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%{0}%'".format( entry.get() )
    # This will work
    select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE City LIKE '%{0}%'".format( entry.get() )        
    # Or this.
    # select_all = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE City == '{0}'".format( entry.get() )
    cursor = sqlite3.Cursor(db)
    cursor.execute(select_all)
    positive = cursor.fetchall()
    print (positive)
    label = tkinter.Label(window,  text="aaaaa")

Button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Search data", command=Search_Completed)
Button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

I'm unable to test the code as I don't have the database so this may have a few errors in it.

Comment: I'd print `select_all` before `cursor = ` to ensure the query is the one you expect.

Comment: Thanks! but i want to search its data by typing the city name in the entry it pulls all the data i will provide the db file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o5qmih93r9izdrt/AAAHev6vc4v6LNt-PzUF5Ggna?dl=0

Comment: Currently the sql statement generated is "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE '%Jakarta%'"  it needs to be either " ... City LIKE '%Jakarta%'" or " ... City == 'Jakarta'". LIKE would match 'Jak' to Jakarta. == only matches if perfectly spelt.